# SSL Error for only one website, meanwhile other one is working | ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: http, security, authentication, ssl, https

I'm editing two websites for my client. He asked for a HTTPS connection.

While one is working perfectly we have a problem in another one (same IP address, same certificate).

**First website throws an error in browser, other one is fine.**

I even made a SSL Report by ssllabs.com and I checked the differences, everything should work fine.

Here is a screen from test:
[DIFFCHECKER SSL COMPARSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APctn.jpg)

Client get ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on both Mozilla Firefox and Chrome as in thread name.

**I guess something is wrong with website, but i don't get it at all.**

Is there anyone who had similar problem or could look at both and tell me where should I search for problems?

Comment: Why not make a separate cert for each domain? You need to automate letsencrypt renewal anyway.

Comment: I don't get any error in the browser, neither in Chrome nor Firefox. I suspect that the client has some local configuration which maps the domain in question to a different IP address. This is not an uncommon setup when developing a site. If the problem is limited to the client then the problem is very likely local to the client and not a problem of the setup of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured this out.

Client was connecting via **www.domain.com** while I was connecting via **domain.com**.

SSL **wasn't configured** by default **to support www** before the domain name.

Why first website was working for client and second not? Because he connected to first one via www and he didn't while connecting to another one. And browser remembered that choice.

**Always check SSL Wildcards fellas!**